# I want to run a python script in UWP C#.

Tags: c#, python, raspberry-pi, uwp

I have bought an RASPI UPS HAT. it's for monitoring the battery voltage in raspberry. I have windows 10 IOT in the raspberry. I can't find anywere how i can accomplish this. If i can't use the python script maybe someone know how i can rewrite it in C#. Here is the example script for this UPS HAT.

```
import struct
import smbus
import sys

def readVoltage(bus):

"This function returns as float the voltage from the Raspi UPS Hat via the provided SMBus object"
address = 0x36
read = bus.read_word_data(address, 2)
swapped = struct.unpack("<H", struct.pack(">H", read))[0]
voltage = swapped * 78.125 /1000000
return voltage

def readCapacity(bus):
"This function returns as a float the remaining capacity of the battery connected to the Raspi UPS Hat via the provided SMBus object"
address = 0x36
read = bus.read_word_data(address, 4)
swapped = struct.unpack("<H", struct.pack(">H", read))[0]
capacity = swapped/256
return capacity


bus = smbus.SMBus(1)  # 0 = /dev/i2c-0 (port I2C0), 1 = /dev/i2c-1 (port I2C1)

print ("Voltage:%5.2fV" % readVoltage(bus))

print ("Battery:%5i%%" % readCapacity(bus))




# draw battery

n = int(round(readCapacity(bus) / 10));

print ("----------- ")

sys.stdout.write('|')

for i in range(0,n):

sys.stdout.write('#')
for i in range(0,10-n):

sys.stdout.write(' ')

sys.stdout.write('|+\n')

print ("----------- ")


if readCapacity(bus) == 100:

print ("Battery FULL")

if readCapacity(bus) < 20:

print ("Battery LOW")
```

Comment: You can [run python script on windows iot core from visual studio](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/helloworldpython).